# Capybara: How to define custom selectors?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I often need to query for elements within the sidebar. However, the css selector that I have to use is temporary and pretty ugly:

```
<div id="rt_mod_side_foo_body_bar">
```

I would like to abstract this so instead of writing:

```
within '#rt_mod_side_foo_body_bar'
```

I can do:

```
within :sidebar
```

How can this be accomplished with Capybara?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a symbol, how about a method?

```
def sidebar
  "#rt_mod_side_foo_body_bar"
end
```

Comment: hmm...where would I put this if I were also using Cucumber? I'm getting undefined method errors